# Much higher cpu usage for usleep on Debian 8 than on Debian 6

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debian

A performance issue is encountered for our software system after we upgraded the OS from Debian 6 to Debian 8.

From the top -H results, it looks like that all the threads using usleep(200) in system have some major CPU usage increasing, then we tested the listed sample program:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    while (true)
        usleep(200);
    return 0;
}
```

On an Intel i3 system (no GUI for OS is enabled, only command line), the program would cause a 1% CPU usage on Debian 6 while it would be 2.3% on Debian 8.

We've checked some suspicious kernel configuration and no useful clue have been found. Also, both OS have enabled high resolution timer.

Debian 8.2 (3.16.0-4):

```
CONFIG_RCU_FAST_NO_HZ=y
CONFIG_HZ=250
CONFIG_HPET_TIMER=y
CONFIG_HPET_EMULATE_RTC=y
CONFIG_HPET=y
CONFIG_HPET_MMAP=y
CONFIG_HPET_MMAP_DEFAULT=y
CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS=y
```

Debian 6 (2.6.32-5):

```
CONFIG_NO_HZ=y
CONFIG_HZ=250
CONFIG_HPET_TIMER=y
CONFIG_HPET_EMULATE_RTC=y
CONFIG_HPET=y
CONFIG_HPET_MMAP=y
CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS=y
```

We know that sub-millisecond sleep would cause some kind of cpu usage while we didn't expect the quite different cpu usage on different OS versions.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you measured, how much does usleep(200) actually sleep on different kernels?

Comment: Also, the CPU usage is a very obscure number. You should not make any conclusions just by looking at the top output. For example, when my system is idle, your program creates ~11% cpu usage, but if I create some artificial load, then your program creates ~5% cpu usage. But the program itself actually runs slower on the idle system. So the CPU usage depends on many things even using the same kernel.

Comment: @ErkiA For your first suggestion, yes, the result looks pretty close to the expected sleep time ~ 200us. Also, the measurement has been carried out when system is idle.